# Realizar una concatenacion de texto con label

Tags: php, html

Hola chicos tengo un problema necesito realizar una lista de texto y que cambie valor segun un dato colocado en un label [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ahora tengo esto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Copia tu código en texto, no en imagen. Indica cuál es tu problema? qué es lo que no funciona con tu código?

Comment: Entre las etiquetas <head></head> no va el cuerpo de la página, solo elementos propios del encabezado de una página HTML.   Quita ese párrafo y ese input y ponlos en el <body>

Comment: y no veo ningún <label>, supongo que te refieres al input. Si necesitas eso de forma dínamica deberás hacerlo con javascript, pero no has realizado ningún intento y la pregunta no es válida tal como está (con imagen y sin intentos), lo siento, te la pueden cerrar por eso.

Comment: Revisa [ask], [tour] y [example] para aprender el funcionamiento **básico** de este sitio, gracias.

Comment: [es.so] te da las herramientas como para compartir el código _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.